# Connecting to a computer in an internal network

Tags: networking, vpn, proxy, vps

I need a way to connect to an internal network of my company from home computer (computer A). I would like to set up some software on my working computer (computer B) at work so that I can access it and the internal network of the company (something like TeamViewer does).

I would prefer to set up some proxy server or VPN on it so that I could connect through it without disturbing people using it. As my work computer can't open ports, I realize that the best option would be to get some extra server in between (like virtual private server), so that work computer connects tto VPS and I connect to VPS from home. Are there any similar solutions available (preferably free) :)

Comment: There is a very nice explanation, how to do that, on this post:
http://superuser.com/questions/610900/vnc-connection-bypassing-firewall-using-vps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution is to build a "reverse tunnel" between your work and home pcs. It is free, and you would not be disturbing other people. It is also very safe, provided you set up authentication by means of "cryptographic keys".

Whether you are on Windows, Mac, or *Nix, there are free programs available to do this job. For Windows it's a free utility called Putty, while ssh is the program for all other pcs.

While not complicated, this requires a modicum of work. You can find a good introduction to this topic [here](http://www.smythies.com/~doug/network/reverse_ssh_tunnel/index.html)